# EBUSY: resource busy or locked, open

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

So im making a discord bot and this error showed up:

```
Unhandled rejection: Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, open 'C:\Users\theno\OneDrive\Dokumente\Discord\Bots\FNFA\FNFA\BotFiles\BotData\variables\servervars.json' at Object.openSync (node:fs:582:3) at Object.writeFileSync (node:fs:2143:35) at Object.module.exports.Message_Handle (C:\Users\theno\OneDrive\Dokumente\Discord\Bots\FNFA\FNFA\BotFiles\Handlers\Message.js:33:8) at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The error is what it says: the file is busy or locked. This is likely due to you placing the bot folder inside of your OneDrive, which is known to cause these problems sometimes. Try moving the folder out of your OneDrive and trying again.

As a side note, you probably shouldn't use JSON if you're going to modify it frequently. Constantly parsing and dumping JSON from/into a file will cause more resource usage, won't scale well, and will cause issues if you make requests in quick succession. Instead, you should consider using a database system (e.g. MongoDB, MySQL, etc.)